# Sublime Text Syntax Highlighting specific php files as js files

Tags: php, javascript, sublimetext

In Sublime Text, I have a handful of .php files that are javascript with a few PHP constants.  How do I get Sublime Text to always syntax highlight these files as JavaScript instead of PHP?  I do not want to do "open all with current extension as..."

Is there a way to set syntax highlighting for specific files or files in a specific folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you open a file in Sublime Text, it'll show you the file type on the bottom right-hand side. If you click on it, you'll get a list of all the file types supported by Sublime Text.

Click on any one of them to temporarily use syntax highlighting for that file type:

[image]

Comment: That is what I always do, but I was looking for a way to set syntax highlighting per a specific file so that when I open that file again it keeps that syntax highlighting and doesn't revert back.